# Vue 3 v-model значение не доходит до методе

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть `input` и его `v-model` (`ticker`), в методе, который срабатывает по `keydown`'у.
Но при введении первого символа `ticker = ""`.

[image: код метода]

Непонятно, почему так происходит, и из-за этого `RegEx` на первый символ получает `""`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда юзер сфокусирован на input и нажимает кнопку на клавиатуре, то происходят следующие события `keydown => input => keyup`.

Соответственно, `v-model` следит как раз за событием `input` и из-за этого вы пытаетесь читать значение, которое ещё не обновлено.

Поменяйте событие на `keyup` или `input` или следите за изменениями `ticker` в watch.

Answer (score 0):

Для `input` элемента необходимо выставить вызов метода по `keyup`, иначе функция вызовется рано.